# Is the zlib-flate algorithm the same one as in Java's Inflate/Deflate algorithms?

Tags: java, scala, zlib

I assumed so (as stated @ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html), but some rudimentary testing seems to show me otherwise:

```
  def compress(data: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = {
    val dis = new DeflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data))
    val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    dis.transferTo(baos)
    val result = baos.toByteArray
    dis.close()
    baos.close()
    result
  }

  Files.write(Paths.get("/tmp/xxx"), compress("a".getBytes("utf-8")))
```

and the result is:

```
usr@usr:/tmp$ xxd xxx
00000000: 789c 4b04 0000 6200 62                   x.K...b.b
```

but running in bash the following gives a different result:

```
usr@usr:/tmp$ echo a| zlib-flate -compress | xxd
00000000: 789c 4be4 0200 00ce 006c                 x.K......l
```

Any clue why the results are different? Is it that the algorithms are just not the same? I've tried just for the sake of it to use different encodings other than utf-8 (ascii and utf-16 and as expected, ascii or utf-8 looked the same for the given input and utf-16 seemed different but not what we are looking for.)

Thanks

Comment: zip is [LZW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch), zlib is [LZ77](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78#LZ77).

Comment: Hi. I may be lost in terminology here, but the Oracle docs state that "his class provides support for general purpose compression using the popular ZLIB compression library." Wouldn't that mean that they are supposed to be the same thing? Thanks